# Stop sweating - viable physical goal?

Tags: running, long-distance-running, running-training-plan, calisthenics

I'm 25% body fat and I sweat a lot. I'm not especially fat at 180cm but the truth is I get winded climbing 3 flights of stairs.

Can I train to reduce fat so that it doesn't insulate my body as much so that I won't heat up and sweat? Also, my heart rate is >90 resting and I have high BP. 140/100.

Comment: From personal experience -- as you lose weight and increase fitness, you will start sweating later. But once you start, the volume of sweat will be the same.

Comment: IMO, your resting heart rate and BP are areas of concern.  You should seek medical advice before attempting any type of physical activity.

Comment: as @rrirower said, medical attention to your BP and resting HR is wise advice, but don't let that stop you from at least walking and other forms of gentle physical activity. You may want medical advice before start vigorous exercise, but it would be harmful to you to avoid all physical activity.

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe that *"stop sweating"* is a good goal simply because, as it stands, it isn't a [SMART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMART_criteria) goal.

You can absolutely train to reduce fat, lower your resting heart rate, and get better and faster at conquering those stairs. However, even the most experienced athletes start sweating at some point. Sweating is your body's natural method of cooling itself down.

So, instead of saying *"My goal is to stop sweating"* I would challenge you to set a SMART goal, something like *"My goal is to climb ten flights of stairs, three times a week"* or *"I will go on a 30-minute walk five times a week."* As you work toward that, three flights of stairs will become easier.

**Before that point**, you should consider approaching a doctor and getting some medical advice; a 90 bpm resting heart rate and 140/100 mmHg blood pressure are both high.

Answer (score 4):

This might not be the answer to the question you've actually asked, but there's too much to put in a comment, so I'm going to risk the downvotes.

Your question suggests that you believe the sweating is being caused by being overweight and thus heating up faster, causing your body to produce sweat as a cooling mechanism. While this may well be the case, temperature regulation [isn't the only reason we sweat](https://www.healthline.com/health/sweating-benefits#what-is-sweat), it also helps the body eliminate heavy metals and some chemicals.

Anecdotally, I've found that my body tends to sweat more for a number of reasons, not directly involving exercise. If I have a couple of nights of bad sleep, I don't keep myself adequately hydrated, my diet goes a bit wonky (think, less vegetables, more package food), I notice myself sweating more.

This is somewhat supported by some Googling around the subject.

[Disrupted sleep leads to a disruption of thermoregulation](http://sleepeducation.org/news/2012/12/18/sleep-deprivation-disrupts-regulation-of-body-heat), which could cause you to sweat more as a compensatory mechanism. Likewise, ingesting more chemically laden food *may* also cause a disruption in thermoregulation as well as just causing your body to try and purge the chemicals it doesn't have any use for (I don't have any links for that, it's partly more a gut feel type thing and partly because I can't access some of the links on the network I'm on at the moment).

So, instead of looking at exercise and "getting fitter" as a way to reduce sweating, it might be worth looking at your sleep and diet instead.

This approach can have the added benefit of helping lose fat; to quote Josh Hillis

> - How much you weigh is determined by how many calories you eat.
> - Your bodyfat percentage is determined by the quality of the food you eat.

That second point is the important one here.

Plus, the lighter you are, the easier you should find it to climb stairs :)